# Hiding rows based on 'Case' statement

Tags: sql-server

I am working on a report that has a huge select list. Few of the columns in the report are condition based. Below are my sample table:

[image]

I want to select c_id, cv_id and medication date only for those clients that have m_is_req = '1'. For other clients who have m_is_req = null should have null for medication data. Also for one client I have multiple medication. So for clients havingm_is_req = null should show only one row. Below is my query. This produces multiple lines for clients having  m_is_req = null.

```
  select c.c_id, c.cv_id,
        case when c.m_is_req = '1' then m.m_id else null end,
        case when c.m_is_req = '1' then m.m_name else null end
from Client c join Medication m
on c.c_id = m.c_id
```

My desired output should be:

[image]

Comment: You might take a look as using a where clause. It is the mechanism used to filter out rows you don't want returned. In your case something like where m_is_req = '1'.

Comment: @SeanLange I want the records to show up but with null. If I add a where clause, it is going to filter and remove those records completely. If I'm not wrong, that is the reason I'm not using the where clause

Comment: I must have misunderstood that part. Have you tried a left join instead of an inner join?

Comment: yes. But still getting multiple rows for client ID 1002 and 1004

Comment: That is because you have multiple rows in the Medication table that meet your criteria. You could use a group by.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `left join` should work. Note the addition of the second condition to the `on` clause. Also, you don't need the `case`s, as all those fields come from `[Medication]`, and will be null because of the join anyway.

```
select c.c_id, c.cv_id, c.m_is_req,
    m.m_id,
    m.m_name 
from Client c 
left join Medication m on c.c_id = m.c_id and c.m_is_req = 1
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/81d25/8) is a fiddle in case you wanted to test it.